# Installed jq in Docker Container - permission denied

Tags: json, docker, jq

I first installed jq for PowerShell using chocolatey (worked) but wasn't able to access it within my running docker container.
Therefore I installed jq in the Docker container via the command I found under this [stackexchange-link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663481/cannot-install-jq-version-1-6-in-docker).

```
curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
```

When I am now trying to access jq for example with the command `jq --version` it says `/bin/sh: 1: jq: permission denied`

How am I able to access jq within the Docker-Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the file executable before you can execute it:

```
chmod u+x /usr/bin/jq
```